# Get default font size of an empty document in Python-Docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I would like to get the default font size of the current document.

**But** the document is empty. There is no paragraph or run I can ask.

The default style "Normal" doesn't have a size set.

```
print(doc.styles['Normal'].font.size)  # None
```

So how can I get it?

One workaround would be to create a paragraph. Ask the runs of this paragraph for its font size and delete it then. But deleting a paragraph isn't that easy and still not implemented. And it is a workaround not a solution.

Technically isn't the default font size somewhere in the documents XML content?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Understanding Styles: Built-in Styles](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html#built-in-styles):

> Word comes with almost 300 so-called built-in styles like Normal,
> Heading 1, and List Bullet. Style definitions are stored in the
> styles.xml part of a .docx package, but **built-in style definitions are
> stored in the Word application itself and are not written to
> styles.xml until they are actually used**. This is a sensible strategy
> because they take up considerable room and would be largely redundant
> and useless overhead in every .docx file otherwise.
>
> The fact that built-in styles are not written to the .docx package
> until used gives rise to the need for latent style definitions,
> explained below.

Even if you add paragraph with default style and ask for it's font size, it will return None

```
from docx import Document
import docx
document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some text')
document.save('test.docx')
print(document.paragraphs[0].text)
style = document.paragraphs[0].style
print(f'Style:{style.name}, font name:{style.font.name}, font size:{style.font.size}')
```

output:

```
A plain paragraph having some text
Style:Normal, font name:None, font size(pt):None
```

Comment: You have to ask the "run" for its font size not the paragraph. But as I told this is a workaround.

Comment: OK, I literally followed your code `print(doc.styles['Normal'].font.size)  # None
` and explanation _create a paragraph. Ask the paragraph for its font size and delete it then_. Anyway, I think the explanation in the docs about built-in styles not being included until used is still valid and relevant